# Symfony2 + Rest login + FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosuserbundle

I don't really understand how to connect my users using a REST api.

For example I can add a new firewall

```
firewalls:
    api:         
        pattern: ^/api
        anonymous: ~
        form_login: false            
        provider: fos_user_bundle
        http_basic:
            realm: "REST Service Realm"
```

But I don't understand how to connect my user.

And once the connection was successful, I have to send datas on each request to prove that my user is connected because there is no cookies.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use http based authentication (as you do with http_basic param) the authentication/authorization is managed by http headers.

The server send to the client an header like this:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="REST Service Realm"
```

That browsers usually alert user with a window thats ask for user/password.

The client should send to the server an header with:

```
Authorization: Basic {string}
```

with string that is the encoded Base64("username:password")

Every request must have this header.

All is described in [RFC 2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I undestand